# Back button that will open main Stage in Javafx 2

Tags: javafx, back, scenebuilder

I have 2 screens in application. First screen(MainController class) which opens with running application from Eclipse.

And second screen(SecondController class) which opens on button located in first screen.

How can I make some kind of 'Back' button in second screen which will show back first screen?

I'm creating the visual part of the application in JavaFX Scene Builder if it matters.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a small example, containing to screens, to show how you can achieve what you are looking for

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TwoScreensWithInterchange extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(loadScreenOne(), 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public VBox loadScreenOne()
    {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        final Button button = new Button("Switch Screen");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                button.getScene().setRoot(loadScreenTwo());             
            }
        });
        Text text = new Text("Screen One");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(text, button);
        vBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #8fbc8f;");
        return vBox;
    }

    public VBox loadScreenTwo()
    {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        final Button button = new Button("Back");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                button.getScene().setRoot(loadScreenOne());             
            }
        });
        Text text = new Text("Screen Two");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(text, button);
        return vBox;
    }

}
```